# Java: critical error- couldn't get class's Field in a Phidget project

Tags: java, class

I'm doing a java project using a phidget accelerometer (phidgets.com) and I get the error

```
sudo java -jar phidgetTester.jar 
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/i386/client:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/i386:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/../lib/i386:/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
    making new phidget
    CRIT: Couldn't get Field ID managerPhidget from phidget_class
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: managerPhidget
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1750)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1675)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:840)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1047)
        at com.phidgets.Phidget.<clinit>(Phidget.java:26)
        at phidgettester.PhidgetTester.<init>(PhidgetTester.java:40)
        at phidgettester.main.main(main.java:15)
```

I get this error when I run my program (sudo java -jar phidgetTester.jar) on one computer but not on another. That is, on my dev system I can build and run the program just fine, but on the system I want to be actually using, I get the above error.
Suggestions for what might be causing the problem?  Is this just a classpath issue (which would be surprising to me) or is it something more sinister?

To install the program, I just copy over the 'dist' folder that's generated by netbeans - it contains the .jar for my program and in the /lib folder is the phidget21.jar file that is necessary for using the phidget drivers on the development machine.

I have run a python test script that is able to read data off the phidgets, so I think the native libraries are fine and the problem is purely java based, but I don't know where in such a small simple program I could have an error that is so contingent on external environment.

Here's my main method (threw in the library path thing just to check that out, but they look basically the same on both machines):

```
package phidgetTester;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
        PhidgetTester tester = new PhidgetTester();

        while(true) {
            SensorData acceleration = tester.getAccelerationData();
            System.out.println(acceleration);
        }
    }    
}
```

And the top of my main class (with some comments and things removed:

```
package phidgetTester;

import com.phidgets.PhidgetException;
import com.phidgets.SpatialEventData;
import com.phidgets.SpatialPhidget;
import com.phidgets.event.*

public class PhidgetTester {

public boolean phidgetfunctional = false;
private final SpatialPhidget sp;
private volatile SensorData compassData;
private volatile SensorData accelerationData;
private volatile SensorData angularData;

public PhidgetTester() throws PhidgetException {
    System.out.println("making new phidget");
    sp = new SpatialPhidget();                   // This is the line it fails on.
    double[] zerodata = {0,0,0};
    this.compassData = new SensorData(zerodata);
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Since neither managerPhidget nor fidget_class, both referred to in the error, appear in the code you posted, you might not get the help you desire...

Comment: yes... I assume that they're buried somewhere in the phidget libraries, but since the some code runs fine, I'm really just looking for information on whta the error means, or if other have had a similar type of problem and might know environmentally what the problems might be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also got the same problem with yours.
I think you need to check if you are using the latest version of the "phidget21.jar" file. For me, the problem happened when I was using the latest Phidget Control Panel and the old "phidget21.jar" file at the same time.
Hope this could help you.

Comment: Thanks... I tried getting the latest version of phidget.jar and alas it has not helped me.  I have two systems that are running the same code, and one has the error and the other does not.  I feel like there's got to be some simple problem like a screwed up ld_library_path or something like that, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Okay, I went back and retried this.  I downloaded the sample code from the phidgets site along with that version of phidget21.jar and it just started working.  I had gotten the jar from somewhere else before, I guess... it was the same version across my systems, but I guess that didn't matter?  Anyway, this ended up fixing it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My assumption would be that you have an old version of the phidget library in your classpath on your second system. Here's a reference to how Java finds particular classes: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/findingclasses.html. Perhaps you can check your classpath for erroneous entries.